# How to implement tooltip in React stateless component

Tags: reactjs

All:

I am pretty new to React, what I try to build is a tooltip response to a hover on a SVG element, for example, I build a STATELESS component like:

```
(props) =>{
var data = props.data;
return (
    <g>
        {
            data.map((d, si) => {
                var logoTrans = "translate(10,"+ si*20+")";
                return (
                    <g transform={logoTrans} key={si}>
                        <rect x="20" y="12"></rect>
                    </g>
                )
            })
        }
    </g>

    <g>
        {
            data.map((d, si) => {
                var logoTrans = "translate(10,"+ si*20+")";
                return (
                    <g transform={logoTrans} key={si}>
                        <text>{d}</text>
                    </g>
                )
            })
        }
    </g>
    )
}
```

What I want to do is to hover each `<rect>` and and according `<text>` shows up(with same si, the text originally `display:none`)

Comment: I'd solve this with CSS.

Comment: @lux Thanks, could you show me how to specify CSS, the rect and text are in parallel level groups?

Comment: Perhaps wrapping the SVG elements with a DIV, and then attaching a class, which picks up the tooltip CSS. That said, you may have luck the non-css route via something like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip Although I've found components for these types of things bit clunky

Answer (score 0):

I've just open-sourced [react-svg-tooltip](https://github.com/netzwerg/react-svg-tooltip) which hopefully addresses your requirements.

It allows to link SVG tooltips to arbitrary SVG elements via references, i.e. it doesn't matter if your `rect` and `text` are in parallel level groups.

All mouse hovering logic is handled behind the scenes. Moreover, the library makes sure that your tooltips are always rendered on top (by usage of a React portal).